# How can I force Entity Framework to allow the DB to create a GUID PK?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this, but I haven't found anyone who has encountered this particular difficulty. For some reason, when I try to insert a record into a table, Entity Framework is generating the GUID PK instead of just retrieving the one SQL Server generates.

I am using Entity Framework Core 5.0.3 and SQL Server 2019. My database tables have the format:

```
CREATE TABLE [Foo].[Bar]
(
    [ID]                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL    ROWGUIDCOL DEFAULT (NEWID()),
    [ClusterID]         BIGINT              NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [CreatedUTC]        DATETIME2(7)        NOT NULL    DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),
    [LastModifiedUTC]   DATETIME2(7)        NOT NULL    DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),
    [SomeData]          NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT          [PK_Bar]            PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT          [UQ_Bar_ClusterID]  UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([ClusterID]),
);
```

My C# objects look like:

```
public abstract class SqlEntity {
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid ID { get; protected set; }

    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ClusterID { get; protected set; }

    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public DateTime CreatedUTC { get; protected set; }

    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
    public DateTime LastModifiedUTC { get; protected set; }
}

[Table("Foo", Schema = "Bar")]
public class Bar : SqlEntity {
    [Required]
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

When the insert executes, Entity Framework is executing code of the form:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Foo].[Bar] ([ID], [SomeData])
VALUES (@p0, @p1);
SELECT [ClusterID], [CreatedUTC], [LastModifiedUTC]
FROM [Foo].[Bar]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ID] = @p0;

',N'@p0 uniqueidentifier,@p1 nvarchar(max)',@p0='42EFBFB1-7FB7-40D1-BE3A-08D8F3082357',@p1=N'Test'
```

This is failing because my `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger discards any values passed for columns that are database generated (thus @p0 isn't the ID).

I understand that I can work around this by relaxing the trigger to `COALESCE([ID], NEWID())`, but I would rather fix the root cause of the problem. I've tried changing `DatabaseGeneratedOption` to `None` and changing the property type to nullable, but both just produced different errors. How do I instruct EF to not generate the GUID PK and instead use the one generated by the database?

Comment: `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` maybe? By the way, I question the need for two columns that represent the ID: clustering could possibly be done on the Created column?

Comment: Unfortunately, `Computed` is the equivalent of `ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()` via the fluent API, so doesn't work (errors out with: _'The property 'ID' cannot be configured as 'ValueGeneratedOnUpdate' or 'ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate' because the key value cannot be changed after the entity has been added to the store.'_). Fair call regarding clustering on Created.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the IDENTITY on the ClusterID, EF should function as expected with 'DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity' on the GUID PK. You'd need to change CreatedUTC to a DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed.  I believe EF is getting confused with the multiple .Identity declarations, probably discarding them since SQL Server only allows one Identity column on a table.

For ClusterID I would recommend creating a Cluster table with an Identity on it's Long PK and using a FK constraint between your "Bar" table to it.

I would advise caution with UUID PKs on tables due to index fragmentation. You can mitigate this partially by using NEWSEQUENTIALID() instead of NEWID() but be prepared for setting up regular index maintenance to keep them a manageable size / performance.

Comment: The point of ClusterID is for the data to be clustered by this (local sequential) key rather than by the GUID PK (that's why the table definition has `PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED` and `UNIQUE CLUSTERED`). This avoids the fragmentation. GUIDs aren't the enemy if you're smart about how you use them. `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` is a mess for distributed systems and should generally be avoided.

Comment: I just tested it with changing ```DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity``` to ```DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed``` on both ClusterID and CreatedUTC. It had no effect on the TSQL that EF produces. I think that these enum values are just poorly named - "Identity" should be "DatabaseComputesOnInsert" and "Computed" should be "DatabaseComputesOnInsertAndUpdate", as they are intended to be equivalent to `builder.ValueGeneratedOnAdd()` and `builder.ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()`.

Comment: How does separating a clustered key that isn't the PK help when FKs will reference the PK not the clustered key??  Yes, NewSequential isn't intended for distributed data systems if that is a requirement. Unfortunately I cannot confirm with EF Core 5 from here, but I used this pattern extensively with EF6 and when set to Identity the generated statements did not even include identity columns in the insert statement. Possibly a bug/"feature" in EF Core 5?

Comment: @Bioinformagician  Using a single NEWSEQUENTIALID() key is fine, even for a clustered primary key.  I'm not sure why you think it should be avoided, but from a performance point-of-view, it's fine.  And certainly better than having two _different_ indexes like you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just simplify your table?

```
CREATE TABLE [Foo].[Bar]
(
    [ID]                UNIQUEIDENTIFIER    NOT NULL    ROWGUIDCOL DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID()),
    [CreatedUTC]        DATETIME2(7)        NOT NULL    DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),
    [LastModifiedUTC]   DATETIME2(7)        NOT NULL    DEFAULT (GETUTCDATE()),
    [SomeData]          NVARCHAR(MAX)       NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT          [PK_Bar]            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID])
);
```

But in any case I'm not seeing that behavior with EF Core 5.0.3 and SQL Server 2019:

```
public abstract class SqlEntity
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }

    public long ClusterID { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreatedUTC { get; set; }

    public DateTime LastModifiedUTC { get; set; }
}

[Table("Foo", Schema = "Bar")]
public class Bar : SqlEntity
{
    public string SomeData { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasKey(b => b.ID).IsClustered(false);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().HasAlternateKey(b => b.ClusterID).IsClustered(true);

    modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().Property(b => b.ID).HasDefaultValueSql("newid()").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().Property(b => b.ClusterID).UseIdentityColumn(1000, 1);


    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Creates

```
CREATE TABLE [Bar].[Foo] (
    [ID] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid()),
    [SomeData] nvarchar(max) NULL,
    [ClusterID] bigint NOT NULL IDENTITY(1000, 1),
    [CreatedUTC] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [LastModifiedUTC] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Foo] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ([ID]),
    CONSTRAINT [AK_Foo_ClusterID] UNIQUE CLUSTERED ([ClusterID])
);
```

and inserts like this

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @inserted0 TABLE ([ID] uniqueidentifier, [_Position] [int]);
MERGE [Bar].[Foo] USING (
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, 0)) AS i ([CreatedUTC], [LastModifiedUTC], [SomeData], _Position) ON 1=0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT ([CreatedUTC], [LastModifiedUTC], [SomeData])
VALUES (i.[CreatedUTC], i.[LastModifiedUTC], i.[SomeData])
OUTPUT INSERTED.[ID], i._Position
INTO @inserted0;

SELECT [t].[ID], [t].[ClusterID] FROM [Bar].[Foo] t
INNER JOIN @inserted0 i ON ([t].[ID] = [i].[ID])
ORDER BY [i].[_Position];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but it doesn't answer the question. I'm happy to have a discussion about the merits of various PK approaches, but there are business and technical constraints that informed DB design which I haven't gone into the details of because they aren't relevant to the question I'm seeking an answer to.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try updating my code to look more like yours and see if that solves the problem. Do you happen to know what EF uses to inform the INSERT TSQL it generates? I assumed the stuff in OnModelCreating would only affect the generation of the migrations, but perhaps that directly or indirectly affects subsequent queries too.